# How to pass table parameters to SQL Server stored procedures in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

All the examples I've seen involve creating a System.Data.DataTable, but that now has no public ctor. What's the recommendation now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SqlDataRecord instead of DataTable as in the sample gist here: https://gist.github.com/divega/f0f88bf16f35641239cfd9bc534e8d7c